# Is there an API to list all Azure Regions?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-regions

I would like to list all Azure locations via some API (I need to generate some config files for every region, and use the exact naming that Azure does to avoid typos). I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41543587/list-all-the-regions-using-the-azure-api), but it only lists regions a particular subscription is authorized to use.

I want to list all regions that exist whether my subscription has access or not.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

`az account list-locations -o table`

will give you a table like:

```
DisplayName               Name                 RegionalDisplayName
------------------------  -------------------  -------------------------------------
East US                   eastus               (US) East US
East US 2                 eastus2              (US) East US 2
South Central US          southcentralus       (US) South Central US
West US 2                 westus2              (US) West US 2
Australia East            australiaeast        (Asia Pacific) Australia East
Southeast Asia            southeastasia        (Asia Pacific) Southeast Asia
North Europe              northeurope          (Europe) North Europe
UK South                  uksouth              (Europe) UK South
West Europe               westeurope           (Europe) West Europe
Central US                centralus            (US) Central US
North Central US          northcentralus       (US) North Central US
West US                   westus               (US) West US
South Africa North        southafricanorth     (Africa) South Africa North
Central India             centralindia         (Asia Pacific) Central India
East Asia                 eastasia             (Asia Pacific) East Asia
Japan East                japaneast            (Asia Pacific) Japan East
JIO India West            jioindiawest         (Asia Pacific) JIO India West
Korea Central             koreacentral         (Asia Pacific) Korea Central
Canada Central            canadacentral        (Canada) Canada Central
France Central            francecentral        (Europe) France Central
Germany West Central      germanywestcentral   (Europe) Germany West Central
Norway East               norwayeast           (Europe) Norway East
Switzerland North         switzerlandnorth     (Europe) Switzerland North
UAE North                 uaenorth             (Middle East) UAE North
Brazil South              brazilsouth          (South America) Brazil South
Central US (Stage)        centralusstage       (US) Central US (Stage)
East US (Stage)           eastusstage          (US) East US (Stage)
East US 2 (Stage)         eastus2stage         (US) East US 2 (Stage)
North Central US (Stage)  northcentralusstage  (US) North Central US (Stage)
South Central US (Stage)  southcentralusstage  (US) South Central US (Stage)
West US (Stage)           westusstage          (US) West US (Stage)
West US 2 (Stage)         westus2stage         (US) West US 2 (Stage)
Asia                      asia                 Asia
Asia Pacific              asiapacific          Asia Pacific
Australia                 australia            Australia
Brazil                    brazil               Brazil
Canada                    canada               Canada
Europe                    europe               Europe
Global                    global               Global
India                     india                India
Japan                     japan                Japan
United Kingdom            uk                   United Kingdom
United States             unitedstates         United States
East Asia (Stage)         eastasiastage        (Asia Pacific) East Asia (Stage)
Southeast Asia (Stage)    southeastasiastage   (Asia Pacific) Southeast Asia (Stage)
Central US EUAP           centraluseuap        (US) Central US EUAP
East US 2 EUAP            eastus2euap          (US) East US 2 EUAP
West Central US           westcentralus        (US) West Central US
West US 3                 westus3              (US) West US 3
South Africa West         southafricawest      (Africa) South Africa West
Australia Central         australiacentral     (Asia Pacific) Australia Central
Australia Central 2       australiacentral2    (Asia Pacific) Australia Central 2
Australia Southeast       australiasoutheast   (Asia Pacific) Australia Southeast
Japan West                japanwest            (Asia Pacific) Japan West
Korea South               koreasouth           (Asia Pacific) Korea South
South India               southindia           (Asia Pacific) South India
West India                westindia            (Asia Pacific) West India
Canada East               canadaeast           (Canada) Canada East
France South              francesouth          (Europe) France South
Germany North             germanynorth         (Europe) Germany North
Norway West               norwaywest           (Europe) Norway West
Switzerland West          switzerlandwest      (Europe) Switzerland West
UK West                   ukwest               (Europe) UK West
UAE Central               uaecentral           (Middle East) UAE Central
Brazil Southeast          brazilsoutheast      (South America) Brazil Southeast
```

Comment: Best, platform agnostic answer.

Comment: This is the kind of answers I love to find and give myself when possible: from an engineer to another fellow engineer on fire. Thanks.

Comment: What it outputs seems to have changed a little now. I'm getting `DisplayName / Name / RegionalDisplayName`

Comment: @bytedev, simply omit [-o table] part and you'll get the fullness of the information in sweet mother JSON format.

Comment: "List supported regions for the current subscription."  this command doesn't list gov regions in my case https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-account-list-locations

Comment: why is malaysia not [listed](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/explore/global-infrastructure/geographies) ?

Answer (score 18):

`Get-AzureRMLocation` will give you the list of locations for your account/tenant/subscription that you run it against.

From the answer below, this works perfectly with the newer version of Azure PS!

```
Get-AzLocation | select DisplayName, Location | Format-Table
```

Comment: I want to list all available locations, even if my subscription doesn't have access (so I know which locations to request access for). Will that still work?

Comment: I believe it uses the same code from the /providers cmdlets - I don't think there is an Azure API for *just* locations, so the cmdlets just wraps the calls like the other solution is doing... but for all resource types in azure, not just VMs

Comment: using azure api sometimes location comes in as a "Display Name" format and sometimes as the "Location" format. For instance location will be "westus2" on a call for SQL server information but it will be "West US 2" for when requesting a list of app services.  It looks as though the lowercase with white space removed version is just that, a lowercase with white space removed.  Is this a trend Microsoft plans to keep up, or is there another way to get one naming convention using the other?  I really wish Microsoft would be more consistent on this.

Comment: Rob - where are you seeing that?  (i.e. how are you getting the location in your case?) - We should be consistent within a "scenario" but there are 2 ways to reference/use location within Azure so different scenarios may expose different values...

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question and already have an accepted answer. But given there have been few changes in Azure Modules hence adding the latest command here.

I do not think the API for location still exists. But with latest version of Powershell Az module you can fetch the locations

```
Get-AzLocation | select DisplayName, Location | Format-Table
```

This gives you some freedom to select the property you need and format the output in tabular format. The AZ CLI command still remains the same as above.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution using powershell script would be to parse the response from the URL: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/. Using this, you could get the information about newly announced regions.

If you do not mind using Java or C#, then the below solutions are handy as well.

1. For region list in java, the dependency in maven is **azure-mgmt-resources** located at https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-java/tree/master/azure-mgmt-resources.
   Documentation: https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/management/resources/fluentcore/arm/Region.html
2. In case you are using c#, the dependency in nuget is **Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent**. And for reference, the Source Code URL: https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/master/src/ResourceManagement/ResourceManager/Region.cs

Comment: Unfortunately this potentially useful URL is returning a 404
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql/db?view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: But how do we get the displayname? This is only the internal names

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking into a way to get the Azure regions without needing to authenticate to Azure and came across this thread. Similar to @girip11's response, I have been building on the public Azure documentation. This is the python script to get the data:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from re import search


def list_azure_regions():
    url = 'https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/explore/global-infrastructure/geographies/'
    html = requests.get(url).content
    df_list = pd.read_html(html)

    regions_list = []
    locations_list = []

    for df in df_list:
        for dc in list(df):
            if search('Regions', dc):
                pass
            else:
                if search('Coming soon', dc):
                    state = 'planned'
                else:
                    state = 'active'

                location = df[dc][0]
                region = dc.removesuffix('  Start free')
                region = region.removesuffix('  Get started')
                region = region.removesuffix('  Coming soon')
                if region in regions_list:
                    pass
                else:
                    regions_list.append(region)
                    locations_list.append(
                        dict({
                            'display_name': region,
                            'name': region.replace(' ','').lower(),
                            'location': location,
                            'state': state
                        })
                    )

    return locations_list

azure_regions = list_azure_regions()
print(azure_regions)
```

The script returns a response of type `<class 'list'>` but could be converted to something more readable if required. I.E. when running on Windows:

```
> python .\get-azure-regions.py | ConvertFrom-Json

display_name         name               location        state
------------         ----               --------        -----
East Asia            eastasia           Hong Kong       active
Southeast Asia       southeastasia      Singapore       active
Australia Central    australiacentral   Canberra        active
Australia East       australiaeast      New South Wales active
Australia Southeast  australiasoutheast Victoria        active
China East           chinaeast          Shanghai        active
China East 2         chinaeast2         Shanghai        active
China North          chinanorth         Beijing         active
China North 2        chinanorth2        Beijing         active
China North 3        chinanorth3        Hebei           active
Central India        centralindia       Pune            active
India South Central  indiasouthcentral  Hyderabad       active
South India          southindia         Chennai         active
Indonesia Central    indonesiacentral   Jakarta         planned
Japan East           japaneast          Tokyo, Saitama  active
Japan West           japanwest          Osaka           active
Korea Central        koreacentral       Seoul           active
Malaysia West        malaysiawest       Kuala Lumpur    planned
New Zealand North    newzealandnorth    Auckland        planned
Taiwan North         taiwannorth        Taipei          planned
Austria East         austriaeast        Vienna          planned
Belgium Central      belgiumcentral     Brussels        active
...
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following REST API:
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/**YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID**/providers?api
-version=2020-10-01

SEE:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/providers/list
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/providers/listattenantscope

But, like the PowerShell and the AZ command line, this only shows data center regions available to the specified subscription.

Comment: This is about providers, not regions.